# How do I loop my animations seamlessly?

Tags: xna, animation, maya

I am trying a complete my method, which crops Maya-Animations (from Maya-Models) to specific ones using the SkinnedModelProcessor.

My only problem is, that after one animation-loop completes, the model stays in its last position for about 2-3 seconds until he catches up to the run-cycle again.

My goal is to get rid of that freeze time.
I want to loop it seamlessly.

Here is what I wrote:

```
public AnimationClip getCurrentAnimation(string clipName, string cropName, float blendTime, int beginFrame, int endFrame, int totalFrames)
{
    //The new list which only has the specific keyframes
    List<Keyframe> region = new List<Keyframe>();

    //The original clip "Take 001" from Maya, which has every
    //animation in one timeline
    AnimationClip clip = _skinningData.AnimationClips[clipName];

    //The new duration of the cropped clip
    int duration = 0;

    //Since XNA makes 7502 frames out of 21, I have to 
    //calc the region-keyframes to proper numbers
    if (endFrame == 0)
        endFrame = clip.Keyframes.Count;
    else
        endFrame = ((endFrame * clip.Keyframes.Count) / totalFrames);

        beginFrame = ((beginFrame * clip.Keyframes.Count) / totalFrames);

    //Start to sort out
        for (int i = beginFrame; i < endFrame; i += 1)
        {
           Keyframe k = clip.Keyframes[i];

           //Add duration of 16 (60fps) to overall-length
           //of animation, if this keyframe does some "real" 
           //transformation, instead of being a static keyframe of XNA
           if (k.Time.Milliseconds > duration)
                duration += 16;

            k.Time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration);
            region.Add(k);
         }

         AnimationClip cropped = new AnimationClip(cropName, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration), region);
         return cropped;
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to have instead of the freeze time? Loop the animation? Go back to default pose? What's stopping you from just switching to the next animation after a loop ends?

Comment: I am trying to loop the animation. It's a run cycle

Comment: For some reason, the start and the end of the loop don't match. That causes a non-fluid loop

Comment: So you either need to make the animations blend, or you need to create animations that end at the same pose they started in. Your question is asking about freezing animations, but you seem to know why it's freezing. Why aren't you asking about how to loop animations?

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I asked

Answer (score 5):

If you want seamless looping animations, create your animations so that the start of the loop is the same pose as the end of the loop. Then when one loop ends, you can simply start playing the second loop without needing to make any changes.

Alternatively, you can blend between the two animation poses. This is where you'll use your `blendTime` value. Spanning the amount of time defined in `blendTime`, use linear interpolation to blend between the last pose of the current animation and the first pose of the next animation.

Comment: One small, probably pointless, addendum:  If the frames per second is low enough, ending on the same position as the loop starts will cause a noticeable hiccup in the animation.  While most games run 30-60 fps, if anyone reading this answer is, for whatever reason, running their animation much slower, a slight adjustment will need to be made.

Comment: @Attackfarm Indeed. I would suggest making the animations start and end on the same frame, but end the loop one frame early, so that it's next frame and the beginning frame are the same.

Comment: So you can ensure me, that the code above is correct?

Comment: Nope. I haven't read through it. I'm answering your question, not correcting your code.